# How to get driver class name (not driver name) from jdbc connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jndi

I have a context.xml file in the below format

```
<Context shallowOutput="true" path="/">
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

  <Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        username="OMITTED"
        password="OMITTED"
        url="OMITTED"
        maxActive="20"
        maxIdle="10"
        maxWait="-1"/>
```

From this contex.xml I need to get my Driver CLASS name.

Everytime I try like

`DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:/jdbc/myDataSource")`

and try to like get the the Driver Class name from the connection using

`ds.getConnection().getMetatData().getDriverName()`

It is returning just
***Oracle JDBC Driver***  instead of the class name **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**

How can I get the class name from the context.

Comment: java.sql.DatabaseMetaData

Comment: If you can get hold of the `DriverManager` for the connection you can then call `getDrivers()` on that and it will give you what you want.

Comment: Out of interest: why do you want to know? There is usually no need to know the implementation class.

Comment: @nigelthomas would you mind accepting an answer?

Answer (score 10):

I think the best you can hope for is:

```
DriverManager.getDriver(ds.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL()).getClass();
```

The metadata should return the URL for this connection and the URL prefix should be registered with the DriverManager (uniquely).

Comment: If you do use this technique, I think you will want to close that connection when you are done.

Answer (score 4):

For any object you can use `object.getClass().getName()`

For JDBC connection it looks like:

```
String db_class = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd).getClass().getName();
```

For my PostgreSQL driver it returns:

```
org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection
```

In your code this should work:

```
ds.getConnection().getClass().getName()
```

And simple procedure that shows class name of connection:

```
public static void show_connection_info(Connection conn)
    {
    System.out.println("Connection: " + conn);
    System.out.println("Connection class: " + conn.getClass());
    System.out.println("Connection class name: " + conn.getClass().getName());
    }
```

For Oracle connection I used in test I got:

```
Connection: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@1e1c66a
Connection class: class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
Connection class name: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection
```

Comment: I need to get the Driver Class name from Context.xml file.

Comment: Instead of `ds.getConnection().getMetatData().getDriverName()` try with `ds.getConnection().getClass().getName()`

Comment: You can always parse XML file :-)

Comment: ds.getConnection.getClass().getName()  will return the class of the Connection.

Comment: It is returning like org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper

Comment: I thought that `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource` will be type of `ds` object. Make sure you are using `getClass().getName()` for `Connection` object

Comment: Can you show us result of `show_connection_info()` from my edited answer?

Comment: I used the method as you had send, but it is still returning the same output.
Connection class: class org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardC
onnectionWrapper
Connection class name: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardCo
nnectionWrapper

Answer (score 0):

I use a "try" algorithm based on reflection. OracleDataSource contains the driver in a "driver" attribute, and there may be lots of DataSource that does the same.
So the following :

```
Field field = dataSource.getClass().getDeclaredField("driver");
field.setAccessible(true);
return field.get(dataSource).getClass().getName();
```

do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Using Tomcat (7) this works:

```
if(source instanceof org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource){
    logger.info("Driver className: "+((org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource)source).getDriverClassName());
}
```

You will also need to include the dbcp library at build time:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp -->
<dependency><!-- to check driver name effectively running -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.47</version>
</dependency>
```