# How to get JDBC Driver class name from connection object during runtime?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have created my JDBC connection like bellow:

```
java.sql.Connection conn =  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DBSID", "DB_USER",
                    "DB_PASS");
```

How can I get JDBC driver class name (e.g. **"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"**) during run-time something like that:

```
String driverClsName  = getDriverClsName(conn);
//e.g.  driverClsName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
```

I've already searched stackoverflow for that but no final solution found.

Already viewed  [How to get driver class name (not driver name) from jdbc connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317215/how-to-get-driver-class-name-not-driver-name-from-jdbc-connection)


What should be code inside below method:

```
String getDriverClsName(Connection conn){
    //code here
}
```

I've already tried `conn.getMetaData().getDriverName();` which is returning **Oracle JDBC driver**.

My requirement is to show information(such as class name) about current driver being used in the application.

Comment: Once you have a `Connection`, why do you need the class name? Also, you should probably be using a connection pool.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My requirement is to show information(such as class name) about current driver using in the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DriverManager.getDriver(String)` should do this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...); 

String originalURL = conn.getMetaData().getURL();
Driver drv = DriverManager.getDriver(originalURL);
String driverClass = drv.getClass().getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following method:

```
conn.getMetaData().getDriverName();
```

Couple of other methods available:

```
conn.getMetaData().getDriverVersion();
conn.getMetaData().getDriverMajorVersion();
conn.getMetaData().getDriverMinorVersion();
```

Comment: Yet not solved. ``conn.getMetaData().getDriverName();`` is returning **Oracle JDBC driver**. Where I need **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**